# Cannot update user display_name field

Tags: plugins, user-meta

I'm trying to update user display name when posted through a form.

Here's what I'm trying:

```
if ( !empty( $_POST['display_name'] ) ){    
    //var_dump($_POST['display_name'] );
    wp_update_user( array ( 'ID' => $current_user->ID, 'display_name' => esc_attr( $_POST['display_name'] ) ) );
}
```

I can see that the display name is posted correctly, but it just does not update it. I can update the user url successfully but not the **display_name** and **first_name**/ **last_name**.
Is there any other way to update these fields?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is because there is no **meta key** named **display_name**, so if you want to update a single meta value better use `update_user_meta` instead of `wp_update_user`, as **[update_user_meta()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_user_meta)** will create the meta field if it doesn't exist.

like

```
if ( !empty( $_POST['display_name'] ) ) {    
    update_user_meta( $current_user->ID, 'display_name', esc_attr( $_POST['display_name'] ) );
}
```

Then you can use the meta key and value the way you want.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, however even this does not work. Its very strange because I can update the user_url and a few other fields with `wp_update_user`. However I cannot update display_name, even with the above answer.

Comment: Can you check if the conditions gets true or not, if true then try and check if you are getting the values for `$current_user->ID` and `$_POST['display_name']` and did you use **update_user_meta**?